# Automatically reloading shiny app when add changes

Tags: r, shiny, xaringan

I would like to have an option (when working locally) which allows me to see changes in my shiny app automatically after I put some changes in `server.R` or `ui.R` file. It is really annoying to manually rerun `runApp` function every time I add a new thing.

The optimal solution which I really like is `xaringan::inifinite_moon_reader` function which is extremely helpful.

Is there any solution which do this stuff?

You can find analogical solution [here](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--62zUz5UZ--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_66%2Cw_880/http://willamesoares.com/images/posts/d3/d3example.gif). On the right, the code was modified and saved, on the left, the content of page was updated.

Comment: Refreshing the page doesn't help? It works for me

Comment: Don't know how. What I really want to achieve to: runApp -> change code in server.R/ui.R file -> save changes. Then an app in the browser should  automatically modify.

Comment: If you run the shiny app in your browser, once you save your changes in server.R/ui.R (or any other file that is sourced by them), you can just hit F5 on your browser to get the updated app

Comment: Ok it works in two-files app. But I would like to avoid "hit F5" step.

Comment: hello from https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/shiny-options.html you can do `options(shiny.autoreload.pattern = glob2rx("ui.R"))` if you want to autoreload tu `UI`

Comment: Thanks! You make my day!

Answer (score 15):

Executing

```
options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)
```

should do the trick.