# Automatically reloading shiny app when error occurs

Tags: r, shiny

This is a follow-up for my previous question [Automatically reloading shiny app when add changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076237/automatically-reloading-shiny-app-when-add-changes).

The solution `options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)` works perfect when you want to automatically see changes on the browser which you put in the code.

However, the potential problem occurs when you save unfinished/corrupted file. For example, the following `ui` code lacks a `,` sign after the `titlePanel` function:

```
fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Datass")
  sidebarLayout(...
```

When you save such a file, you will get an error on your browser

```
ERROR: Error sourcing your_path/ui.R
```

R console will help detect the problem with the `,` sign. My impression was that if I improve my code and save the file, it should `reload` the browser and show my app correctly. Unfortunately, it doesn't do it.

Interesting thing is that an error in the app does not terminate the connection with the browser. To confirm my word, just reload the app manually using reload button in the browser (after improving your code).

Therofore, I examined how this `shiny.autoreload` option works. As I expected, it checked the time of file modification and then execute `reload` function. Then `reload` function send a message via `sendMessage` to the `addMessageHandler`:

```
addMessageHandler('reload', function(message) {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

So it seems that after improving your code the function should be reexecuted, but it's not gonna happen.

To summarise, I think it's not possible to change it without major changes in `shiny` but maybe I am wrong. Thanks for any suggestion.

PS.You can manipulate example code [here](https://gist.github.com/Nicolabo/7d0a75740ef1a95ceda4a026c0ba13d5) to see the problem.